# How can I match and filter a dataset using another one?

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I really dont know how to ask about this so let me give an example.

I have a dataset which has over 50k+ entries including adresses. Like this

```
streets <- c("st1","st2","st3","st4","st10000","st50000")
```

I need to match this street names to cities they are belonged to. When it sees "st1" it should add CityX. I didnt have a dataset so I've created one like this.

```
cities <- data.table(
  city1 <- c("st1","st2","st3"),
  city2 <- c("st4","st5","st6"),
  city3 <- c("st50","st10000","st50000")
  )

setnames(cities,"V1","NY")
setnames(cities,"V2","LA")
setnames(cities,"V3","DC")
```

Now I want to match this datasets if cities include street names it should create a new column in "streets" and add city name to there. Should be seen like this:

```
streets2 <- data.table(streets <- c("st1","st2","st3","st4","st10000","st50000"),
c("NY","NY","NY", "LA","DC","DC"))
```

I should mention that I cant use dpylr for this only data.table is allowed. I think I need to use for loop and lapply but idk how. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really have data in this form as one comma-separated string?

Comment: I have a huge data set with over 55k entries in 1 column... I've been creating another dataset to categorize this values.

Comment: You should share an example that exactly represents your data otherwise you'll have difficulty applying the answers to your data.  Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Ok I'll try it now ty.

Comment: Why would you want the output as a comma separated string?

Comment: Its my bad I just fixed my question now. I started to learn R almost a month ago ... still forgetting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option:

```
teams <- c("barcelona","rmadrid","liverpool")
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(mget(teams), function(x) data.table(Player=trimws(strsplit(x,",")[[1L]]))),
    idcol="Team")

data.table(Player=strsplit(players, ",")[[1L]])[DT, on=.(Player), Team := Team][]
```

output:

```
     Player      Team
 1:    Xavi barcelona
 2:   Puyol barcelona
 3: Iniesta barcelona
 4:   Messi barcelona
 5: Gerrard liverpool
 6:   Salah liverpool
 7:    Mane liverpool
 8: Ronaldo   rmadrid
 9:   Ramos   rmadrid
10:  Hazard   rmadrid
```

Hasn't Xavi, Puyol and Gerrard retired? And Ronaldo is still at Real Madrid?

data:

```
players <- "Xavi,Puyol,Iniesta,Messi,Gerrard,Salah,Mane,Ronaldo,Ramos, Hazard"
barcelona <- "Xavi,Puyol,Iniesta,Messi"
rmadrid <- "Ronaldo,Ramos,Hazard"
liverpool <- "Gerrard,Salah,Mane"
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not interested in football too much but I couldnt find a better example :) This doesnt work for me. I guess I couldnt express myself correctly. Let me try to fix that. 

I have a column(dataset1) with 50k+ entries some of them are repeating values. I have to categorize this but I didnt have another dataset so I've created one which includes 50+ categories and each different value in dataset1. So when R sees "xxx1" in dataset1 it should look it up in dataset2 and add its category value near "xxx1" if there is a match. Like I said probably i need lapply and for loop but idk.